# Network Activity on Mac OSX Monterey not showing all processes

Tags: networking, macos, ps

My network activity is showing that I'm downloading huge amounts of data that are not showing up in my activity monitor.   Is there a program I can use that actually works?

I tried `launchctl list` but I didn't know what to do after that.

I also tried `ps -ax |more` but couldn't figure anything out.

I tried editing /private/etc/hosts and setting

```
0.0.0.0 compute-1.amazon.aws.com
0.0.0.0 sea.github.com
0.0.0.0 104.21.81.187
0.0.0.0 1e100.net
0.0.0.0 akamaitechnologies.com
0.0.0.0 chromecast.home
0.0.0.0 github.com
0.0.0.0 amazonaws.com
0.0.0.0 webnx.com
0.0.0.0 cloudflareresearch.com
```

but it did nothing

I also turned on my firewall and set it to block all incoming connections.  Still no change.  9GB d/led now and counting.

I also tried looking at `nettop` but i don't know which of these are doing the d/ling.   See below the image for output from nettop.

IS IT NORMAL FOR ITEMS TO DISAPPEAR FROM NETTOP?  I SEE CERTAIN ENTRIES SHOW UP FOR LIKE HALF A SECOND AND THEN VANISH.

[image]

***NETTOP***

```
Stats.31473
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54080<->ec2-3-232-242-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54078<->ec2-54-91-59-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443
   udp4 *:*<->*:*
   udp4 192.168.1.3:60504<->172.67.163.100:443
   udp4 192.168.1.3:56984<->104.21.81.187:443
Stats.31513
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54090<->cdn-185-199-109-133.github.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54088<->lb-192-30-255-112-sea.github.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54086<->108-171-202-195.static.webnx.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54085<->lb-192-30-255-116-sea.github.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54084<->ec2-3-232-242-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443
   udp4 *:*<->*:*
   udp4 192.168.1.3:50710<->104.21.81.187:443
Stats.31561
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54096<->cdn-185-199-109-133.github.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54095<->108-171-202-195.static.webnx.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54093<->lb-140-82-112-3-iad.github.com:443
   tcp4 192.168.1.3:54092<->ec2-3-232-242-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443
   udp4 *:*<->*:*
   udp4 192.168.1.3:51787<->104.21.81.187:443
   

 ➜  ~ nettop                   
    
    
    kernel_task.0
    launchd.1
    systemstats.98
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
    configd.100
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
    syslogd.124
    apsd.129
       tcp4 192.168.1.3:50922<->17.57.144.121:5223
    PerfPowerServic.145
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
    bluetoothd.151
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
       udp4 *:*<->*:*
    AirPlayXPCHelpe.155
       udp4 *:*<->*:*

**launchctl list**


    Last login: Tue Jun 14 00:24:49 on console
    ➜  ~ launchctl bslist -j
    Unrecognized subcommand: bslist
    Usage: launchctl <subcommand> ... | help [subcommand]
    ➜  ~ launchctl list     
    PID Status  Label
    -   0   com.apple.SafariHistoryServiceAgent
    -   0   com.apple.progressd
    -   0   com.google.keystone.user.xpcservice
    -   0   com.apple.cloudphotod
    401 0   com.apple.Finder
    515 0   com.apple.homed
    557 0   com.apple.SafeEjectGPUAgent
    -   0   com.apple.quicklook
    -   0   com.apple.parentalcontrols.check
    519 0   com.apple.mediaremoteagent
    444 0   com.apple.FontWorker
    438 0   com.apple.bird
    -   0   com.apple.amp.mediasharingd
    -   0   com.apple.familycontrols.useragent
    -   0   com.apple.AssetCache.agent
    -   0   com.apple.GameController.gamecontrolleragentd
   

 -  0   com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn
    -   0   com.apple.UserPictureSyncAgent
    447 0   com.apple.nsurlsessiond
    -   0   com.apple.devicecheckd
    -   0   com.apple.syncservices.uihandler
    441 0   com.apple.iconservices.iconservicesagent
    555 0   com.apple.diagnosticextensionsd
    791 0   com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent
    -   0   com.apple.LinkedNotesUIService
    1354    0   com.apple.ndoagent
    -   0   com.apple.bookassetd
    -   0   com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.agent
    -   0   com.apple.localizationswitcherd
    -   0   com.apple.screensharing.agent
    569 0   com.apple.commerce
    -   0   com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync
    -   0   com.apple.installerauthagent
    -   0   com.apple.languageassetd
    -   0   com.apple.familynotificationd
    624 0   com.apple.photolibraryd
    -   0   com.apple.xpc.otherbsd
    -   0   com.apple.sysdiagnose_agent
    -   0   com.apple.tipsd
    -   0   com.apple.timezoneupdates.tznotify
    471 0   com.apple.TextInputMenuAgent
    -   0   com.apple.bluetoothUIServer
    -   0   com.apple.assistant_service
    -   0   com.apple.MRTa
    431 0   com.apple.CommCenter
    408 0   com.apple.trustd.agent
    -   0   com.apple.MailServiceAgent
    -   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail
    -   0   com.apple.appkit.xpc.ColorSampler
    391 0   com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent
    -   0   com.apple.coreimportd
    -   0   com.apple.TrustedPeersHelper
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_arm64_1
    -   0   com.apple.DataDetectorsLocalSources
    -   0   com.apple.unmountassistant.useragent
    -   0   com.apple.keyboardservicesd
    488 0   com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent
    1434    0   com.apple.Safari.PasswordBreachAgent
    -   0   com.apple.csuseragent
    454 0   com.apple.ContextStoreAgent
    -   0   com.apple.AOSPushRelay
    -   0   com.apple.accessibility.AXVisualSupportAgent
    -   0   com.apple.xpc.loginitemregisterd
    -   0   com.apple.applespell
    -   0   com.apple.coreservices.UASharedPasteboardProgressUI
    -   0   com.apple.screensharing.menuextra
    -   0   com.apple.warmd_agent
    -   0   com.apple.dt.xcodepreviewsapp
    481 0   application.com.google.Chrome.6765461.12886033462
    -   0   com.apple.universalaccesscontrol
    -   0   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
    -   0   com.apple.findmymacmessenger
    -   0   com.apple.FilesystemUI
    -   0   com.apple.maps.destinationd
    500 0   com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent
    -   0   com.apple.pluginkit.pkreporter
    -   0   com.apple.systemprofiler
    425 0   com.apple.cloudd
    -   0   com.apple.noticeboard.agent
    -   0   com.apple.UserNotificationCenterAgent
    -   0   com.apple.cmfsyncagent
    -   0   com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand
    -   0   com.apple.ATS.FontValidator
    470 0   com.apple.diagnostics_agent
    -   0   com.apple.appleseed.seedusaged
    -   0   com.apple.LocalAuthentication.UIAgent
    602 0   com.apple.ap.adprivacyd
    687 0   com.apple.ap.promotedcontentd
    -   0   com.apple.PhotoLibraryMigrationUtility.XPC
    445 0   com.apple.apfsuseragent
    483 0   com.apple.networkserviceproxy
    398 0   com.apple.controlcenter
    678 0   com.apple.AMPLibraryAgent
    -   0   com.openssh.ssh-agent
    -   0   com.apple.atsd
    -   0   com.apple.tonelibraryd
    -   0   com.apple.WeatherService
    1280    0   com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration
    -   0   com.apple.security.KeychainStasher
    497 0   com.apple.ctkd
    -   0   com.apple.package-script-service
    418 0   com.apple.secinitd
    568 0   com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd.x86_64
    -   0   com.apple.contacts.donation-agent
    -   0   com.apple.ServicesUIAgent
    1644    0   com.apple.synapse.contentlinkingd
    -   0   com.apple.XprotectFramework.PluginService
    -   0   com.apple.ctkbind
    -   0   com.apple.mediastream.mstreamd
    -   0   com.apple.alf.useragent
    507 0   com.apple.triald
    405 0   com.apple.tccd
    -   0   com.apple.nexusd
    511 0   com.apple.StatusKitAgent
    593 0   com.apple.replayd
    492 0   com.apple.coreservices.uiagent
    -   0   com.apple.icloud.searchpartyuseragent
    -   0   com.apple.AccessibilityVisualsAgent
    -   0   com.apple.installd.user
    502 0   com.apple.akd
    1823    0   application.com.apple.Terminal.1152921500311988367.1152921500311988372
    499 0   com.apple.CallHistoryPluginHelper
    -   0   com.apple.storeaccountd
    -   0   com.apple.AddressBook.AssistantService
    -   0   com.apple.PIPAgent
    -   0   com.apple.mbfloagent
    -   0   com.apple.printtool.agent
    461 0   com.apple.askpermissiond
    -   0   com.apple.USBAgent
    -   0   com.apple.ssinvitationagent
    -   0   com.apple.webinspectord
    -   0   com.valvesoftware.steamclean
    -   0   com.apple.avatarsd
    -   0   com.apple.speech.synthesisserver
    -   0   com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent
    -   0   com.apple.storeuid
    -   0   com.apple.rcd
    -   0   com.apple.printuitool.agent
    -   0   com.apple.NVMeAgent
    -   0   com.apple.speech.speechdatainstallerd
    -   0   com.apple.AOSHeartbeat
    475 0   com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.ahp.agent
    -   0   com.apple.SafariNotificationAgent
    -   0   com.apple.coredatad
    472 0   com.apple.remindd
    -   0   com.apple.appsleep
    -   0   org.macosforge.xquartz.startx
    451 0   com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd
    -   0   com.apple.screencaptureui.agent
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_x86_64_1
    -   0   com.apple.netauth.user.auth
    -   0   com.apple.siri-distributed-evaluation
    413 0   com.apple.ViewBridgeAuxiliary
    -   0   com.apple.mbbackgrounduseragent
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64
    400 0   com.apple.lsd
    676 0   com.apple.siri.context.service
    417 0   com.apple.pluginkit.pkd
    -   0   com.apple.security.XPCTimeStampingService
    572 0   com.apple.cache_delete
    -   0   com.apple.symptomsd-diag.agent
    437 0   com.apple.AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent
    -   0   com.apple.accessibility.dfrhud
    -   0   com.apple.CallHistorySyncHelper
    1356    0   com.apple.colorsync.useragent
    903 0   com.apple.appleaccountd
    489 0   com.apple.parsecd
    -   0   com.apple.mlruntimed
    397 0   com.apple.Dock.agent
    512 0   application.com.divisiblebyzero.Spectacle.3683255.3683490
    -   0   com.apple.parsec-fbf
    432 0   com.apple.dmd
    -   0   com.apple.transparencyd
    490 0   com.apple.AppSSOAgent
    -   0   com.apple.mbuseragent
    409 0   com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3
    392 0   com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua
    1227    0   com.apple.followupd
    516 0   application.OpenObject.fuspredownloader.9715076.9715084
    443 0   com.apple.identityservicesd
    449 0   com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd
    -   0   com.apple.DwellControl
    653 0   com.apple.security.DiskUnmountWatcher
    527 0   com.apple.CoreLocationAgent
    1355    0   application.com.apple.ActivityMonitor.1152921500311961084.1152921500311961089
    595 0   com.apple.SecureBackupDaemon
    -   0   com.apple.security.agent
    -   0   com.apple.cfnetwork.AuthBrokerAgent
    -   0   com.apple.multimodalsearchd
    618 0   com.apple.storedownloadd
    -   0   com.apple.SpacesTouchBarAgent.app
    469 0   com.apple.BTServer.cloudpairing
    -   0   com.apple.coreparsec.silhouette
    434 0   com.apple.coreservices.sharedfilelistd
    411 0   com.apple.pboard
    -   0   com.apple.nowplayingtouchui
    -   0   com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.fudHelperAgent
    -   0   com.apple.reversetemplated
    -   0   com.apple.SafariCloudHistoryPushAgent
    -   0   com.apple.BTServer.le.agent
    -   0   com.apple.AskPermissionUI
    -   0   com.apple.thermaltrap
    430 0   com.apple.rapportd
    610 0   com.apple.SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager
    -   0   com.apple.accounts.dom
    -   0   com.apple.metadata.mdflagwriter
    -   0   com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper
    -   0   com.apple.mdworker.shared
    -   0   com.apple.mdworker.single.x86_64
    -   0   com.apple.usermanagerhelper
    -   0   com.apple.installandsetup.migrationhelper.user
    420 0   com.apple.containermanagerd
    558 0   com.apple.SafeEjectGPUService
    504 0   com.apple.imdpersistence.IMDPersistenceAgent
    -   0   com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent
    -   0   com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays
    526 0   com.apple.neagent.878568F8-CCE5-4157-8315-22F20DC8FB0A
    424 0   com.apple.accountsd
    520 0   com.apple.cdpd
    439 0   com.apple.routined
    416 0   com.apple.siriactionsd
    -   0   com.apple.KeyboardAccessAgent
    446 0   com.apple.BiomeAgent
    -   0   com.apple.storelegacy
    -   0   com.apple.OSDUIHelper
    486 0   com.apple.audio.AudioComponentRegistrar
    667 0   com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService
    -   0   com.apple.DiagnosticsReporter
    -   0   com.apple.lockoutagent
    -   0   com.apple.locationmenu
    -   0   com.apple.videosubscriptionsd
    498 0   com.apple.pbs
    429 0   com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent
    521 0   com.apple.protectedcloudstorage.protectedcloudkeysyncing
    458 0   com.apple.imklaunchagent
    -   0   com.apple.imcore.imtransferagent
    -   0   com.apple.btsa
    459 0   com.apple.icdd
    -   0   com.apple.ckdiscretionaryd
    -   0   com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert
    -   0   com.apple.metadata.mdwrite
    -   0   com.apple.loginwindow.LWWeeklyMessageTracer
    -   0   com.apple.XprotectFramework.scan
    423 0   com.apple.CalendarAgent
    -   0   com.apple.securityuploadd
    -   0   com.apple.RapportUIAgent
    485 0   com.apple.siriknowledged
    -   0   com.apple.powerchime
    463 0   com.apple.sharingd
    -   0   com.apple.iCloudUserNotificationsd
    -   0   com.apple.metrickitd
    -   0   com.apple.storeassetd
    506 0   com.apple.familycircled
    -   0   com.apple.FontRegistryUIAgent
    -   0   com.apple.RemoteManagementAgent
    480 0   com.apple.TextInputSwitcher
    679 0   com.apple.AMPArtworkAgent
    468 0   com.apple.imagent
    -   0   com.apple.sidecar-relay
    1334    0   com.apple.photoanalysisd
    -   0   com.apple.syncservices.SyncServer
    -   0   com.apple.imautomatichistorydeletionagent
    399 0   com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
    -   0   com.apple.PackageUIKit.InstallStatus
    -   0   com.apple.ATS.FontValidatorConduit
    396 0   com.apple.talagent
    623 0   com.apple.suggestd
    -   0   com.apple.navd
    -   0   com.apple.RemoteDesktop.agent
    544 0   com.apple.iCloudNotificationAgent
    473 0   com.apple.amsaccountsd
    -   0   com.apple.VoiceOver
    -   0   com.apple.AssistiveControl
    530 0   com.apple.icloud.fmfd
    -   0   com.apple.mdworker.single.arm64
    448 0   com.apple.FileProvider
    402 0   com.apple.secd
    477 0   com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice
    1289    0   com.apple.BKAgentService
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64_1
    482 0   com.apple.assistantd
    -   0   com.apple.studentd
    -   0   com.apple.FollowUpUI
    450 0   com.apple.videoconference.camera
    -   0   com.apple.corespotlightservice
    -   0   com.apple.uikitsystemapp
    -   0   com.apple.controlstrip
    1335    0   com.apple.mediaanalysisd
    -   0   com.apple.DiskArbitrationAgent
    -   0   com.apple.assessmentagent
    -   0   com.apple.exchange.exchangesyncd
    -   0   com.apple.testmanagerd
    -   0   com.apple.dt.AutomationModeUI
    1274    0   com.apple.scopedbookmarksagent.xpc
    -   0   com.apple.ensemble
    -   0   com.apple.ReportCrash
    1060    0   com.apple.biomesyncd
    554 0   com.apple.UsageTrackingAgent
    -   0   com.apple.email.maild
    428 0   com.apple.donotdisturbd
    -   0   com.apple.menuextra.battery.helper
    -   0   com.apple.appleseed.seedusaged.postinstall
    -   0   com.apple.Maps.mapspushd
    -   0   com.apple.voicememod
    -   0   com.apple.gamed
    -   0   com.apple.STMUIHelper
    -   1   homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
    467 0   com.apple.knowledge-agent
    -   0   com.apple.midiserver
    421 0   com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent
    -   0   com.apple.mobiledeviceupdater
    1125    0   com.apple.helpd
    -   0   com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper
    493 0   com.apple.wifi.WiFiAgent
    -   0   com.apple.screensharing.MessagesAgent
    -   0   com.apple.diskspaced
    -   0   com.apple.passd
    -   0   com.apple.DictationIM
    -   0   com.apple.sociallayerd
    -   0   com.apple.mdmclient.agent
    -   0   com.apple.iCloudHelper
    -   0   com.apple.CharacterPicker.FileService
    2307    0   com.apple.mdworker.shared.04000000-0700-0000-0000-000000000000
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_x86_64
    -   0   com.apple.security.XPCKeychainSandboxCheck
    501 0   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.agent
    410 0   com.apple.syncdefaultsd
    -   0   com.apple.sidecar-display-agent
    -   0   com.apple.accessibility.heard
    453 0   com.apple.corespeechd
    -   0   com.apple.AMPSystemPlayerAgent
    406 0   com.apple.itunescloudd
    -   0   com.apple.scrod
    542 0   com.apple.spindump_agent
    -   0   com.apple.AquaAppearanceHelper
    -   0   
    
        com.apple.AuthenticationServicesCore.AuthenticationServicesAgent
        -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_arm64
        -   0   com.apple.bookdatastored
        522 0   com.apple.security.keychain-circle-notification
        -   0   com.apple.appstorecomponentsd
        -   0   com.apple.icloud.findmydeviced.findmydevice-user-agent
        -   0   com.google.keystone.user.agent
        605 0   com.apple.amsengagementd
        -   0   com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent
        1059    0   com.apple.proactiveeventtrackerd
        -   0   com.apple.proactived
        395 0   com.apple.universalaccessd
        -   0   com.apple.accessibility.MotionTrackingAgent
        -   0   com.apple.neagent
        559 0   com.apple.SafariLaunchAgent
        -   0   com.apple.idsfoundation.IDSRemoteURLConnectionAgent
        -   0   com.apple.recentsd
        508 0   com.apple.WiFiVelocityAgent
        422 0   com.apple.usernoted
        616 0   com.apple.geodMachServiceBridge
        -   0   com.apple.translationd
        -   0   com.apple.AddressBook.abd
        -   0   eu.exelban.Stats.LaunchAtLogin
        -   0   com.apple.ScreenReaderUIServer
        -   0   com.apple.newsd
        426 0   com.apple.contactsd
        484 0   com.apple.swcd
        466 0   com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent
        -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_arm64_1
        -   0   com.apple.dt.previewsd
        -   0   com.apple.shazamd
        576 0   com.apple.corespotlightd
        -   0   com.apple.netauth.user.gui
        -   0   com.apple.watchlistd
        442 0   com.apple.xtyped
        -   0   com.apple.TMHelperAgent
        479 0   com.apple.Spotlight


  664   0   com.apple.appstoreagent
    -   0   com.apple.AMPDevicesAgent
    -   0   com.apple.accessibility.mediaaccessibilityd
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_x86_64_1
    1670    0   com.apple.mdworker.sizing
    -   0   com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd
    549 0   com.apple.metadata.mdbulkimport
    -   0   com.apple.iokit.IOServiceAuthorizeAgent
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_arm64
    -   0   com.apple.Safari.History
    407 0   com.apple.carboncore.csnameddata
    -   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_x86_64
    -   0   com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd.arm64
    -   0   com.apple.CoreRoutine.helperservice
    389 0   com.apple.distnoted.xpc.agent
    570 0   com.apple.geod
```

Comment: Note that the `/etc/hosts` file can't contain port numbers.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you, I wasn't sure if that was allowed or not.  I did try it both ways, however, and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by closing all open programs and just watching `nettop`,  I began adding any domains that showed up on nettop to my /private/etc/hosts file with the following entries..

```
0.0.0.0 compute-1.amazon.aws.com
0.0.0.0 sea.github.com
0.0.0.0 104.21.81.187
0.0.0.0 1e100.net
0.0.0.0 akamaitechnologies.com
0.0.0.0 chromecast.home
0.0.0.0 github.com
0.0.0.0 amazonaws.com
0.0.0.0 webnx.com
0.0.0.0 cloudflareresearch.com
```

Then using `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` after editing etc/hosts to make the changes take effect.

Eventually, the network activity dropped to ~0 so I new one of the entries was the culprit.

Then just a matter of removing them 1 by 1 to figure out which one is the problem, and then make sure that one stays routed to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer.